# In C#, String is a reference type or not?

Tags: .net, string, c#-3.0, clr

Example:

```
String Str1="Hello";

String Str2=Str1;

Str1="Welcome";

Console.Writeline(Str1); //output is Welcome

Console.Writeline(Str2); //output is Hello
```

if String is reference type, then Str2 value should come as Welcome right?

Thanks.

Comment: You're creating a new `string` with `Str1 = "Welcome"`. They no longer point to the same string reference.

Answer (score 0):

Make a little change then Str2 would come Welcome try this.

```
String Str1 = "Hello";

        Str1 = "Welcome";

        String Str2 = Str1;


        Console.WriteLine(Str1);
        Console.WriteLine(Str2);
```

Comment: That's not really "making a change to `Str2`", you're just doing the same thing in a different order. The end *behavior* of the strings is still the exact same.